# WPF Checklist Binding with ComboBox Select

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, listbox

I'm still new to WPF and Binding so please be as specific as possible.  I am trying to build a list of objects to a ListBox of checkBoxes that I would like to bind with a Combobox.  When the Combo box is selected, I would like the ListBox of checkBoxes to be refreshed.  The ListBox loads perfectly on the first load but doesn't refresh when the list of objects change.  I have debugged, and I can see that the Objects are changing it just the UI isn't being triggered.  Any help would be nice, thank you ahead of time.

ComboBox

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0"   SelectionChanged="JobTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                              Name="JobTypeComboBox"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllJobTypes}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                              SelectedValuePath="Name"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=JobConfig.SelectedJobType.Name}" />
```

ListBox checkboxes

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllDocTypes}" Height="177" Name="listTopics" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Checked="DocTypeCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="DocTypeCheckBox_UnChecked"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Constructor

```
public ConfigControl() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    LoadSettings();
}
```

Attributes

```
// Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name) {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}

public JobConfiguration JobConfig {
    get { return _jobConfig; }
    set {
        _jobConfig = value;
        // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
        OnPropertyChanged("JobConfig");
    }
}

public DocTypeList AllDocTypes {
    get { return _allDocTypes; }
    set {
        _allDocTypes = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AllDocTypes");
    }
}
```

ComboBox Select Change

```
private void JobTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    //set the new jobtype selected
    //load settings for that job type
    ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
    JobType selectedJob = (JobType)cmb.SelectedItem;
    JobConfig.SelectedJobType = selectedJob;
    AllDocTypes.SetDocTypeIsChecked(JobConfig.SelectedJobType.DocTypes);
    OnPropertyChanged("JobConfig");
    OnPropertyChanged("AllDocTypes");
}
```

DocType Classes

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ISO_Validation_And_Processing.Models {

public class DocType {
    [XmlElement]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; } = false;
}

public class DocTypeList : List<DocType> {
    public static DocTypeList Read(ISerializeManager serializeManager) {
        if (serializeManager != null) {
            return serializeManager.ReadObject<DocTypeList>();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public DocTypeList() { }

    public void SetDocTypeIsChecked(DocTypeList selectedDocs) {
        foreach (var docType in this) {
            docType.IsChecked = IsDocTypeSelected(docType, selectedDocs);
        }
    }

    public bool IsDocTypeSelected(DocType docType, DocTypeList selectedDocs) {
        //if there is a doctype with the same name return true
        return selectedDocs.Where(t => t.Name == docType.Name).ToList().Count > 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How and where is AllDocTypes "refreshed"?

Comment: Is `AllDocTypes` an ObservableCollection<>?

Comment: Sorry added the constructor

Comment: @mm8 I thought that when I call OnProperterChanged("AllDocTypes"); that would trigger the 2 way binding.

Comment: Yes, but where do you actually update/change the collection?

Comment: @mm8 Right before when i set the checkboxes: AllDocTypes.SetDocTypeIsChecked(JobConfig.SelectedJobType.DocTypes);

Comment: Post the SetDocTypeIsChecked method then.

Comment: @mm8 Just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DocType` class should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications when the `IsChecked` property is set:

```
public class DocType : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _isChecked;
    [XmlElement]
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then the `CheckBox` should be updated whenever you call the `SetDocTypeIsChecked` method.

Comment: Could you refactor this answer to use my 2 classes so i can better understand to implement?

Comment: You need to re-implement your DocType class as per my edited answer.